# Making conditional probability density from multivariate normal distrubution projection

Tags: probability

I have modelled my data probability density $p(x,y,z)$ as multivariate normal.
Can I treat now the projection of this function $p(x,y,z=a)$ as conditional
probability density $p(x,y | z=a)$ ? Can I expect it will be 2-dimensional normal distribution?

Thank you!
Pavel

Answer (score 1):

> Can I treat now the projection of this function $p(x,y,z=a)$ as conditional
>   probability density $p(x,y | z=a)$ ?

No, in the rather sloppy language you are using, the conditional
probability density $p(x,y | z=a)$ is $p(x,y,a)/p(a)$, not $p(x,y,a)$. Hence your suggestion misses a factor independent of $(x,y)$ (bad news) but $p(x,y,a)$ indicates the shape of $p(x,y|z=a)$ (good news).

Comment: You are right! Of course! So it was correct assumption up to a constant factor p(a). Otherwise integral over all (x,y) space of p(x,y,a) would not be 1.